# Resharper Intellisense Auto Import

Tags: c#, resharper

There is a neat little feature in the Resharper Intellisense where it suggests items which are in a namespace you haven't imported yet.

e.g. if you type in `StreamReader` the Intellisense is showing me the item `StreamReader (in System.IO)` and if I press enter it is importing the namespace and everything is fine.

But it seems like this feature is just working for System types and not types you have written yourself.

consider the following example:

```
namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        internal static void Main()
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace Test.Util
{
    internal class Helper
    {
    }
}
```

Let's say you want to use your `Helper`-class in the `Main`-method. While you are writing `Helper` you won't get an entry in the intellisense drop down menu like in the `StreamReader` example. When you exit the intellisense drop down you will get the import message `Import 'Test.Util.Helper' and all other references in the file` where you can import all missing references.

Is there any way to extend this 'auto import'-feature to show my self-written classes in the intellisense drop down or is this just something I'll have to live with

Comment: It works for me... I've just tried your exact example, and typing "Helper" in `Main` offered "Import type 'Test.Util.Helper'"

Comment: This works fine, but what I am talking about is the 'auto-import' in  the intellisense. e.g. When you just type in `Help` it is not showing you an entry like `Helper (in Test.Util)` in the Intellisense drop down.

Comment: You should make your question clearer then - because you specifically say you won't get a suggestion if you type `Helper`, when actually you do - albeit not in quite the same context.

Comment: If I type help, I do get `Helper` listed in intellisense. If I select it, resharper automatically adds the using statements. I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, but its not working at my Visual Studio. Do you have the newest version  of Resharper installed? I think it used to work in older versions.

Comment: I'm using resharper 8.0. What version do you have? I believe this feature exist for a long time, not sure though.

Comment: I'm using version 9. Could be a feature that has been removed. I think I'll send in a support request at Jetbrains and ask them myself. Thx for your help guys

Comment: Have you tried to use the double smart completion feature?

Comment: double smart completion is not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetbrains support:

> We fixed such issue in ReSharper 9.1 branch and the fix will be
>   available after ReSharper 9.1 release. Unfortunately, we do not have
>   exact date of the release.

Comment: What is the name of this little feature that you have? how to you call it? I really liked it a lot. that's my most used feature on the resharper. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can always use import-completion mode when ordinary completion doesn't suggest import items for some reason. It's invoked by Ctrl+Alt+Space.

In your sample, if you write "Hel" and invoke Ctrl+Alt+Space, the item will be auto-imported.

Comment: Are you using Resharper 9? I have Resharper 9 and it is not working

Comment: Yes, I use ReSharper 9. It works: http://screencast.com/t/mP43cc4AV. Does normal ReSharper IntelliSense work for you? Could you please provide a screenshot with ReSharper-suggested items? Thanks.

Comment: My view: [link](http://imgur.com/A8rlfdE). Could you send my your Resharper C# Intellisense settings, maybe I can find the error there.